# The stylesheet http://localhost/portfolio/faq/assets/css/faq.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using friendly url, but when I use  / on final  url string, it shows the error

> The stylesheet http://localhost/portfolio/faq/assets/css/faq.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

but when I remove  the /, it works.

How to fix ?

Comment: Is there any need to add the '/' at the end of your tag? It's not necessary in order for your stylesheet to be referenced.

Comment: because the user can to use with / or no /

Comment: By closing link with '/' you're using XHTML syntax as opposed to HTML and it's not being parsed.

Comment: Perhaps try changing your document type declaration to support XHTML?

Answer (score 0):

Here, when i put / on final, it show this on source code: localhost/portfolio/faq/assets/css/faq.css, but the file path is localhost/portfolio/assets/css/faq.css if me remove the / it work with the file path correct.